graphlearning with two part of tuning and not tuning with both under CV resampling
I want to have a mlr3 pipeline that the first pipe is filtering without tuning, and then it follows with classifiers with tuning. I want the both part be inside CV, but only second part be on gridsearch.
pipe=   po("filter", filter = flt("anova") ,filter.frac = .5) %>>%  
  po("pca", rank.=10) %>>% po('learner', lrn('classif.log_reg', predict_type = "prob"))
plot(pipe)

paramset <- ParamSet$new(list(
  ParamDbl$new("classif.log_reg.epsilon", lower = 0, upper = .000001 ),
  ParamDbl$new("classif.log_reg.maxit", lower = 5, upper = 40,tag = 'budget' )#,

))

I am using TuningInstanceSingleCrit and whole my graph is going through grideasrch which cause lots of extra time. these are part of settings:
 instance <- TuningInstanceSingleCrit$new(
  task = task,
  learner = grf_lrn,
  resampling = cv10,
  measure = msr("classif.auc"),
  search_space = paramset,
  terminator = trm('none')
 
)

I am wondering how I can have CV run on all graphlearner but gridsearch only apply to classif.log_reg.
for example I want to have for each fold, Anova be calculated and pass to LR and tuning be done only on LR.
Thanks.

If I understand correctly, you're already doing this -- if you don't expose any parameters for the filtering, it won't be tuned.

Thanks for your respond. Yes, it won't be tuned but Anova is calculated every time for each new configuration(set of hyper parameters) even though the results is the same. I want to keep it out of gridsearch so it will be calculated once. Do you have any solution for that. Thanks.

Does this cause that much overhead in practice? It should be very cheap comparatively.

Yes it does, There is large number of features. So my goal is to have Anova run once outside gridsearch. I appreciate any input and suggestions.

You could use an AutoTuner for just the logistic regression.
